# Kite live editing

Tags: emacs, swank, kite, swank-js

I really like the idea behind [Kite](https://github.com/jscheid/kite) – using WebKit's own protocol for remote debugging. No need for a proxy socket server or a bookmarklet to connect to a web-page (that's how [swank-js](https://github.com/swank-js/swank-js) operates).

The project's readme states that Kite...

> "enables ... live-editing Web pages".

However, while `kite-scratch` works fine, I can't eval defuns or whole buffer while *not* in the kite scratch.

**Is it possible to eval JavaScript with Kite in any buffer other than kite-scratch?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `kite-scratch-mode` is a mode derived from `javascript-mode`, so you might just be able to use <kbd>M-x kite-scratch-mode</kbd> to enable the `kite-scratch` bindings in your javascript file.

I'm sure it's not designed for that, though, and so you might consider asking the author for a minor mode which supplies bindings similar to those of `swank-js` or `js-comint`.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. When you do `kite-scratch-eval`, it says `kite-session-websocket accessing a non-kite-session`.

Comment: Steve, I've made a request for the minor mode. Thanks!